# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified (Openai-universe)

Tags: openai-api, openai-universe

I am trying to install universe but every time i do `pip install universe` i get this error `[WinError 2]The system cannot find the file specified` this is **NOT** the full error the full error goes like this:

```
Collecting universe
  Using cached universe-0.21.3.tar.gz (136 kB)
Collecting autobahn>=0.16.0
  Using cached autobahn-20.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting docker-py==1.10.3
  Using cached docker_py-1.10.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting docker-pycreds==0.2.1
  Using cached docker_pycreds-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.5 kB)
Collecting fastzbarlight>=0.0.13
  Using cached fastzbarlight-0.0.14.tar.gz (728 kB)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER-A~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1vxwxj7j\\fastzbarlight\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ANAN-A~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1vxwxj7j\\fastzbarlight\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ANAN-A~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-k7u0i11p'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1vxwxj7j\fastzbarlight\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1vxwxj7j\fastzbarlight\setup.py", line 49, in <module>
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['ld', '-liconv'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

and after those words have been mentioned i get:

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output`

Comment: My ide is spyder

Comment: If you have information to add, use the [edit] link below the tags to do so. The only time you should be using a comment as the question poster is when you're responding to someone else who has left a comment for you.